# FullCalendar - Recommendations for saving time zone in database

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to build up a web-based application (php, js, mysql), which will contain fullcalendar. I don't think, that I will need timezone-support, but I think it would be better to implement it better now than later ...

I googled around and made some test, but I think I would need some recommendations regarding the database. I have never worked with time Zone Information till now ...

What would you recommend for saving timezone Information into the database?
I thought about:

- MySql-Column with timestamp (=UTC) like "1475764940" and the timezone like "+02" in a separate column.

or

- MySql-Column in DateTime (containing Information in UTC) and the timezone in a separate column.

or

- .....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do for fullCalendar to work with timezones is store your times as UTC and then use the library [jstz](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) for handling the timezones.

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var timezone = tz.name();
```

Then you can pass your timezone along with your events url as a parameter in your get request.

```
events: {
        url: "calendarManager.php?request=get&timezone=" + timezone + "&userid=" + userID,
}
```

Then in your calendarManager you can deal with converting the UTC times to the users timezone for the returned events and just make sure inserted and updated events are sent to the database in UTC which can be done easily with the included [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Hello Ryan, 
Thank you. Your answer was very helpful. That sounds quit good. I will overthink, if this is suitable with in my project.
Which data-type would you recommend for the mysql column? DateTime or saving as Unix Timestamp?

Comment: Do you have experience - Are there cases, that jstz doesn't detect the users time Zone? How do you handle These? Take the Servers time Zone then?

Comment: I have never had that problem. jstz gets the timezone from the users device so unless there is something wrong with that I think it would be fine. I could see it not working if Javascript was disabled but then obviously your calendar would not work either. I don't think the server time would be useful at all but it could be a fallback if needed but then times would not be accurate. Saving the timezone to a cookie or even to a users profile and comparing and updating or verifying the timezone  if it's found could be a better solution.